# Android Room - IN condition

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am trying to implement a Room query which gets a list of integers that Room can use to return a list of entries based on that. Has anyone found a solution for that?

In the direction of that:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM article_entries WHERE id IN :itemIds")
fun loadAll(itemIds : List<Int>): LiveData<List<Article>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM article_entries WHERE id IN :itemIds")
```

with:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM article_entries WHERE id IN (:itemIds)")
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but only with Java. Kotlin seems to have a problem with that..

Comment: @Mordag: I do not see an outstanding issue related to this. If you can create a reproducible test case, [file an issue against the Architecture Components](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448).

Comment: I have created the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64904791 Thanks.